# A basic qeustion about taylor theorem

Tags: calculus

$$P_2(x)=f(x_0)+f'(x_0)(x-x_0)+\frac{f''(x_0)}{2}(x-x_0)^2$$

The polynomial $P_2(x)$ is a second degree polynomial which "unifies" with $f$ in 3 elements:

$P_2(x_0)=f(x_0)$

$P'_2(x)=f'(x_0)+f''(x_0)(x-x_0)$

$P'_2(x_0)=f'(x_0)$

$P''_2(x)=f''(x_0)$

$P''_2(x_0)=f''(x_0)$

I am sorry for the bad writing, there maybe a mistake there, I am trying to understand what are those 3 elements that "unifies"

Comment: What don't you understand? What are you asking? Yes, the $n$-th order Taylor polynomial agrees with $f$ up to order $n$ at $x_0$.

Comment: @symplectomorphic what does "agrees with $f$ up to order n at $x_0$ means? it has the same value in n points?

Comment: @gbox: that a function $g$ "agrees with $f$ up to order $n$ at $x_{0}$" means that for $0 \leq k \leq n$ the values at $x_{0}$ of the $k$th derivatives of $f$ and $g$ are the same.